# spatialpolygonsdataframe polygons jumbled after merge to join data

Tags: r, plot, merge, shapefile, r-maptools

I'm trying to plot some Turkish data using R.

The problem I'm having is when I merge my data with the shape file (in spatialpolygonsdataframe  format) the data no longer matches the correct pologons.  What am I doing wrong,

Below is some reproducible code.  The shape file is some [natural earth data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) (so public domain) and I've put it on my google drive zipped with the simple data excel file.
It produces 2 plots with the province name plotted, before and after the merge.
You can see that the second image has "jumbled" the data and the Turkey.map@data no longer matches the correct polygon.

Before merge plot with correct province names:
[image: before merge]
After merge plot:
[image: after merge]

```
library(maptools)
library(readxl)

temp <- "TurkeyShapefile.zip"
URL      <- "https://docs.google.com/ucid=0B0TyKM0aACIONUxfNTJwWGhrR0k&export=download"
download.file(URL,temp, mode="wb")
unzip(temp)

trtr <- readShapeSpatial("Natural_earth_admin_RMS150518_TR")

#read excel file
fname <- "TR_data.xlsx"
TRdata <- read_excel(fname, sheet = "pcnt")

Turkey.map <- trtr       #create copy of trtr

#a plot of the map before the merge
plot(Turkey.map)
invisible(text(getSpPPolygonsLabptSlots(Turkey.map), labels=as.character(Turkey.map@data$Admin1Name), cex=0.5))


#merge (join data)
Turkey.map@data <- merge(Turkey.map@data,TRdata,by.x="Admin1Name",by.y="Province", all.x=TRUE)

#a plot of the map after the merge
plot(Turkey.map)
invisible(text(getSpPPolygonsLabptSlots(Turkey.map), labels=as.character(Turkey.map@data$Admin1Name), cex=0.5))
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're in for a world of pain if you do anything with the `@data` slot on a spatial object that could in any way reorder it. In general you should do everything by manual calls to `which()` on an ID field between matched data sets, or alternatively in your case, you can call `merge()` on the `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` object itself:

```
Turkey.map <- merge(
    Turkey.map, TRdata, 
    by.x="Admin1Name", by.y="Province", 
    all.x=TRUE
)
```

Curious as to why the OP wasn't seeing the correct output from merging a `Spatial*` object with a `data.frame` this is a fully reproducible example showing the correct behavior:

```
library(sp)

##  Reproducible 10x10 grid of polygons:
set.seed(2002)
grd <- GridTopology(c(1,1), c(1,1), c(10,10))
polys <- as(grd, "SpatialPolygons")
centroids <- coordinates(polys)
x <- centroids[,1]
y <- centroids[,2]
z <- 1.4 + 0.1*x + 0.2*y + 0.002*x*x
d <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(
  polys,
  data=data.frame(
    x=x, y=y, z=z, ID=1:length(x), 
    row.names=row.names(polys)
  )
)

df <- data.frame("ID"=1:10, color="black")

class(d)
class(df)
```

Yields:

```
class(d)
[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
class(df)
[1] "data.frame"
```

And following on to merge the two:

```
##  The merge of a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and a data.frame:
dm <- merge(d, df, by.x="ID", by.y="ID", all.x=T)

##  Verify we still have a Spatial* object:
class(dm)
names(dm)
```

Yields:

```
class(dm)
[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
names(dm)
[1] "ID"    "x"     "y"     "z"     "color"

plot(dm, col=dm$color)
```

[image]

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices
[4] utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] sp_1.1-1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.1     grid_3.2.1     
[3] lattice_0.20-31
```

Comment: That would just create a data frame object though, replacing the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame of the same name would it not?

Comment: No, it returns the same `Spatial*` class object you supply the merge function with.

Comment: I did try it first, it returned a dataframe object!
I tried a sort=FALSE to the merge which I think may have fixed it in this case.
Thanks

Comment: If you are indeed still working with a `data.frame` object (which you shouldn't be as long as you're merging the actual `Spatial*` object and not its `@data` slot) you shouldn't rely only on `sort=F` to return a `data.frame` suitable for sticking back into the `Spatial*` object. The reason is that with `all.x=T` specified any non-matches still end up reordered at the bottom of the resulting merged `data.frame` object. This may be a comment for future readers, if indeed the merge is giving you back your `Spatial*` object as it should.

Comment: yep, I used your exact code instead of the merge line in mine. No longer a spatial object.
so I went back to
`Turkey.map@data <- merge(Turkey.map@data,TRdata,by.x="Admin1Name",by.y="Province", all.x=TRUE, sort=FALSE)`

I have since tried

Comment: I have since tried to (avoid using merge and) use match which seems to work fine. `Turkey.map@data = data.frame(Turkey.map@data, TRdata[match(Turkey.map@data[, "Admin1Name"], TRdata[,"Province"]),])`

Comment: I'm genuinely curious as to why you aren't seeing the appropriate behavior. I've added a reproducible example to my answer to prove how the behavior should work with a current version of `sp` and the `sp::merge()` functionality.